# XCode 6 : instantiate a ViewController without an identifer?

Tags: ios, xcode

I would like to instantiate a new Viewcontroller using this :

```
 FirstViewController *FirstViewController =
[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MonthView"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:FirstViewController animated:YES];
```

But since I would like to use the view MonthView with 4 different ViewControllers I can't use this method because I can't link the view to a class.

Can I instantiate a ViewController Without an Identifer?

Answer (score 0):

`-instantiateViewController:` takes as argument identifier of ViewController you specify in Storyboard -> Identity Inspector -> StoryboardID.

It has nothing to do with views.

Comment: So how can i start a ViewController that isn't linked to a view storyboard?

Comment: Same way you are trying to in your example code. You just need to correctly specify identifier, as i have explained in my answer.

Comment: but since i want to use the same View with 4 ViewControllers, the view only opens when i click on button 1, and crashes whith the other 3. It's because I assign the view with ViewController1.. any idea of making it work ?

Comment: I am sorry, what exactly do you mean by 'using the same view with 4 ViewControllers' ?

Comment: I have a StoryboardView with 4 Buttons, I would like use it with 4 ViewControllers.

Comment: The your problem is using one view with multiple ViewControllers, not what your initial question was.